# How to get Locale from mock context

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to do some unit testing, and I haven't really settle yet on a runner or test class.

At the end, this is the method I'm verifying it works:

```
public static void getData(final Context context, final Callback<MyObject> callback) {

    Locale locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
    MyObjectService myService = new MyObjectService(getRequestHeaders(context), locale);
}
```

So I need a mock context that has resources, configuration, locale and SharedPreferences.

I've tried PowerMockito, AndroidTestCase, AndroidTestRunner, ApplicationTestCase. All I can get is a mock Context with nothing in it, or mock Resources, but I can't figure out how to add them to the mock context (basically remake a Context).

This is currently my last attempt (although I've tried more complex ones, without any success):

import com.myApp.android.app.shop.util.ServiceUtils;

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import android.content.Context;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestLogin
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
        ServiceUtils.getData(context, dataCallback);
    }
}
```

The exception I get is a NPE from getData() as the passed context does not have resources.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is not an easily mockable system.  I too have tried using Mockito to mock the framework, but it quickly becomes extremely complex.  Things like resources and SharedPreferences are not easy to mock.  These problems have been tackled in 3rd-party APIs like Robolectric.

I suggest you use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) for your Android unit tests.  Robolectric runs in a standard VM (i.e. no emulator needed).  Robolectric simulates the majority of the Android system, thus minimizing (but not eliminating) the need to build mocks.  I have found it to be a very useful tool for Android TDD.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So far I've been able to make robolectric work on basic tests, but I have been unable to verify the value coming back from a callback. Would you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As a second answer (and maybe more useful than the first) I suggest you to split the logics from the platform's dependencies.

In this way you can consider to unit test the logic in a pure-java way.

Take a look on MVP pattern. It should helps a lot!

In this case, for example, you would move this line...

```
MyObjectService myService = new MyObjectService(getRequestHeaders(context), locale);
```

... inside a "Service" that is completely a pure-java class allocated by a constructor that require (in this case) a String value called "locale" and a data structure called "headers"

Easy, no? ;)

My 2 cents: everytime that you need Robolectric to test logics (instead of UI) you probably make a mistake

Comment: Yeah that's an option and we could break the methods apart. I was looking for an option to test against existing methods and network calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RuntimeEnvironment by Robolectric

```
Locale locale = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

Comment: I just did, but I can't figure out how to validate the response in the callback from retrofit (1.9)

Comment: this is another problem :)

Comment: what you mean with "validate the response"?

Comment: I'm using now Robolectric and I get the network data like this:         "ServiceUtils.getData(context, dataCallback);" this is either in the Before method or the Test method. Both work. But the retrofit callback returns a success and failure method. In the success method it returns an object. I need to validate this object with Robolectric (or anything really) to verify the data is the correct object type and with the correct elements in it.